# How can I make a random element of my page stick to the top bar when scrolling down?

Tags: flutter

I have used the mobile Spotify app on my device for the first time and I have noticed how the play/pause Button that is scrolling with the site, but to the top.
Now I am asking myself: How could I implement this in Flutter?

How could I make the Appbar become opaque from transparent with scrolling?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use SliverAppBar

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html check this documentation and try to search the `App bar with floating: true, pinned: true, snap: false:` part

Answer (score 0):

I have this special widget i build it on my own, hope this could help you

Note: give this widget ScrollController that connect to the listview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:tvri/PORTRAIT/themes/my_themes.dart';

class SliverBar extends StatefulWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  const SliverBar({
    super.key,
    required this.scrollController,
    required this.title,
    this.leading,
    this.actionButton,
    this.centerTitle = true,
    this.titleSpacing = 0.0,
    this.withLeading = true,
  });
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  final dynamic title;
  final Widget? leading;
  final List<Widget>? actionButton;
  final bool centerTitle;
  final double titleSpacing;
  final bool withLeading;

  @override
  State<SliverBar> createState() => _SliverBarState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(60);
}

class _SliverBarState extends State<SliverBar> {
  double visibleCount = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
  }

  scrollListener() {
    double maxHeight = Get.statusBarHeight;
    double offset = widget.scrollController.offset;

    if (offset < maxHeight) {
      setState(() {
        visibleCount = offset / maxHeight;
      });
    } else if (offset > maxHeight && visibleCount < 1.0) {
      setState(() {
        visibleCount = 1.0;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // <-- SEE HERE
        statusBarIconBrightness:
            Brightness.light, //<-- For Android SEE HERE (dark icons)
        statusBarBrightness:
            Brightness.light, //<-- For iOS SEE HERE (dark icons)
      ),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: MyThemes.colorBlue.withOpacity(visibleCount),
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: widget.centerTitle,
      titleSpacing: widget.titleSpacing,
      leading: widget.withLeading
          ? widget.leading ??
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.back();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left, size: 24),
              )
          : null,
      title: widget.title is String
          ? Text(
              widget.title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: MyThemes.colorWhite,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            )
          : widget.title,
      actions: widget.actionButton,
    );
  }
}
```